# start process from ssh and be able to close connection

Tags: shell, ssh, process, raspberry-pi, putty

I'm connecting to my RaspberryPi with Raspbian installed via ssh and my problem is, that I can't let the RasPi do things (installing software, make calculations) while my Computer is shut down, since the processes I launch via SSH are child processes of the SSH shell and are terminated when the connection ends. I know i can disconnect child processes from the shell, but I'm not sure which way to use and it i would like to be able to see as much of the output of the process as possible (maybe in a file?).

BTW: I'm using PuTTY from Windows 7 :(

Answer (score 2):

There's a little tool called screen which is able to do this from you. You can detach from a screen session and let it run in background so you can close the SSH connection. After reconnection you can reatach to the screen.

http://thesystemadministrator.net/cpanel/how-to-install-and-use-screen-in-linux

Comment: looks good, i'll try it out :)

Comment: GNU screen is called [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) these days. ;)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.